# Gallery only shows 1 image, How to resolve?

Tags: android

I am trying to set up a gallery within my code of several images but the problem I am having is that the gallery is only displaying one image from my array, the first image only can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Thanks

code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ThumbsIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView imageView = null;
    if(convertview==null){
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(250,230));
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    }else{
        imageView =(ImageView)convertview;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(ThumbsIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

public Integer[] ThumbsIds ={
        R.drawable.seanpic,
        R.drawable.billypic,
        R.drawable.actor_1
};
```

}

Comment: You'll have to actually implement `getItem(int)` and `getItemId(int)`. Also, use `int` as the data-type for your array, as `Integer` will result in boxing/unboxing which slows you down.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Hey, Could you help me with how to do that?  The tutorial I am watching somehow did not change any of them yet his still worked.

Comment: Also, you don`t need to implement `SpinnerAdapter`, `BaseAdapter` already does that.

Comment: @TylerM.  I ave tried setting the  getItem and getItemId to return the position from the array but this does not work, Is this the wrong way?

Comment: Does the galler only show only a single image, or three images which are the same?

Comment: @ChrisConway  The gallery only shows a single image